# jQuery Slider image slider with scrolling navigation and fixed active state

Tags: jquery, css

I have managed to get this 80% of the way there and it's working great. I am stumped on one last thing.

**What it does:**
Currently when you use the next/prev navigation is moves all the list items in an infinate rotatation and the active list item stays the same

**What I wished it did:**
Use the next/prev I would like the active state to remain stationary(visually) as the list items rotate pass through this position, calling the new content to the slide area.

Thanks in advance for you help.
Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eFJSg/18/

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to help you with this? Thats alot to do.

Comment: @ Shawn - I know it's lots to do, I have been wrestling with it for a could days now. I was hoping to get a point in the right direction with the right theory to do it. I'll keep looking for an out of the box solution.

Comment: I creating an plugin so far but its so big now I would never dare to post it here because people are just really mean because your code is so huge its uneditable. From now on I will just ask my team.

Comment: @ Shawn, I'm sorry, but you lost me there.

Comment: Well, im creating a plugin, and its rather big. And I dont post it on Stack Overflow because usually no one will answer. But if you wan't you can come here: https://weebuild.campfirenow.com/room/377975. And I will try and help you.

Comment: Wait, never mind, I got to go. You can email me tomorrow at: shawn@weebuild.biz. I will try and help you finish your code.

Comment: Also, the link I gave you is a chat that I now blocked from any other access.

Comment: Well email me anytime from 4-10pm tomorrow if you want to get on the chat to talk further.

Comment: @ shawn, I've worked on this for awhile, but I got it pretty far. If you have any tips on how to manage the last bit of the puzzle that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

The simple fix is to wrap the code that is triggered when you click any button on the right side of the slider in a function (with some modifications) and call the function in the next/prev `click()` triggers.

The modifications would include finding the active button, selecting the next button, and setting the active class on that. You've already coded the mechanism to move the list up or down.

### Option 2

Your second option is to make a separate div with the `active` class and place it beneath the button list on the right (that is, at a lower `z-index`).

This way, you don't really need to complicate the code with something that cycles the buttons through the active class. The only downside is that you'd need some minor modification to the `click` event on any of the buttons, because currently you transfer the active class. You could just use the same mechanism as you do with the next button and have the clicked button move up the list.